# ValueError with XGBoost on Multi-Class Dataset: Expected Classes 0-8, Got 0-9

Tags: python, xgboost, multiclass-classification

I am encountering a `ValueError` when running an XGBoost model on a multi-label dataset. The error message is:

```
ValueError: Expected class labels {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, got {0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

My dataset consists of 500 instances, with labels ranging from 0 to 9, making it a total of 10 classes. The minority class (label `9`) has 37 instances. Despite this, I am receiving an error indicating an unexpected class label `9`.

I have already tried using different values for cross-validation (3, 5, and 10) without success. Interestingly, other models from `sklearn`, such as Random Forest and AdaBoost, do not produce this error and work as expected.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with XGBoost or can identify a possible cause for this error? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: First off, it's multi-class classification **NOT** multi-label. Please include complete error traceback.

Comment: Did you check your class labels, `y_train` and `y_test`? It seems one of them is missing instances with class label `2`.

Comment: I used StratifiedKFold and somehow there is a fold that the class "2" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would check:

1. XGBoost requires class labels starting from 0, going up to `n_classes - 1`.

> By default, XGBoost assumes input categories are integers starting from 0 till the number of categories [0, n_categories) [[ref](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/categorical.html#miscellaneous)]

To check that `y` meets this format, try `print(np.unique(y))` - it should be `[0, 1, 2, ..., n_classes - 1]`.

If not, `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` can map the original `y` to the appropriate format.

2. The relatively small dataset size, combined with specifying a test size of 0.2, means that infrequent labels might not appear in the test set.

To enforce sampling from all labels in both splits, try modifying your code to `train_test_split(..., stratify=y)`. Everything as before, but this time ensuring that the test split's label distribution is close to the original, so it won't miss any labels.

I think stratifying is a good idea even if you weren't getting the error (especially when there's imbalance), as it makes the test split's distribution representative of the original dataset rather than having a distribution that has been distorted by the random sampling process.

Comment: What about StratifiedKFold? I used it for cross-validation. It still did not work.

Comment: That would rule out #2. I think #1 could still be an issue - running `print(np.unique(y))` should give you [0, 1, **2**, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].

Comment: I am not sure why "2" in the class is ruled out. It has similar count as class "1". I saw in the last Fold the "2" is ruled out but other Folds are OK.

Comment: `y_test=2` is missing from the last fold? I assume `y=2` is present when you run `print(np.unique(y))` - it should print numbers 0 to 8 including *all* integers in-between. (#1/#2 in my previous comment refers to the numbered points in my answer, not the labels `y`).

Comment: I know what you mean. The thing is class "2" is missing during the last fold, which is strange.

Comment: Is `shuffle=True` in the CV splitter you're using? If the data is ordered and `shuffle=False`, then the splitter might be missing the `y=2` segment of the data. Setting `shuffle=True` will mix it up so each fold will likely have all the classes.

Comment: Still not working. That is strange. Only the XGB fails.

Comment: I applied many resampling strategies. One of them is EditedNearestNeighbours. I am not sure if is not compatible with XGB or something.